# What's the difference between 'war' and 'wars'?

Tags: verb

I know 'war' is the Präteritum tense of 'sein', but what's happening when an 's' is added here?

> Ich wars

> It was me

Over

> Ich war

> It was

---

This is in the Oxford - German dictionary.

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with that kind of declination of verbs. Sorry I appreciate this is really basic question.

Comment: Just be glad you haven't read "I bims" for "Ich bins" yet...

Comment: "Ich war" doesn't mean "It was"; it means "I was." "Ich wars" is a contraction of "Ich war es.", literally "I was it."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Often people write *wars* sloppily in written colloquial speech. Both variants, *wars* and *war’s*, are a reduced form of *war es*. “Ich war es” is the correct translation of “It was me”.

That *wars* is as possible as *war’s*. So your dictionary is correct.

The rule behind that is [here](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/apostroph#D14), and *wars* is meant appropriately:

> In den folgenden Fällen wird üblicherweise kein Apostroph gesetzt:
>
> 4. bei Verbindungen der Kurzform des Pronomens es mit dem vorangehenden Wort – sofern das Lesen nicht erschwert wird.
>
>    Zum Beispiel:
>
>    - Wie gehts (auch: geht’s) dir?
>    - Sie machte sichs (auch: sich’s) bequem.
>    - Wenns (auch: Wenn’s) weiter nichts ist …
>    - Aber eher: Sie weiß, wo’s langgeht.

translation of Duden entry:

> Usually no apostrophe is used in the following cases:
>
> 4. When combining the short form of the pronoun es with the preceding word – as long as reading is not made difficult.
>
>    For example:
>
>    - How are you?
>    - She made herself comfortable.
>    - If is nothing more …
>    - But rather: she knows what’s going on.

Comment: Agh! Thank you. Damn Oxford German Dictionary app.

Comment: Do you have a source for the claim that the apostrophe is obligatory?

Comment: @DavidVogt: Thanx, you're right. I have corrected my answer now. :)

Comment: I'm quite sure it was not allowed a few years ago. It still looks wrong to me without apostrophe. Maybe a result of the spelling reform which allowed a lot of weird things.

Comment: I second the opinion that it looks wrong without apostrophe.

Comment: @äüö I can't remember a time where it wasn't allowed. So it must predate 1996.

Comment: "wars" looks wrong to me too, but these things evolve over time. 40 years ago you would also write "in's" (into the), nowadays everyone uses "ins"...

Answer (score 6):

*Bins* and *wars* are mergers of the verb forms [*bin*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/bin) and [*war*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/war#war_(Deutsch)), respectively (1<sup>st</sup> and 3<sup>rd</sup> person singular indicative of [*sein*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/sein)), with the personal pronoun [*es*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/es#Personalpronomen). Or shorter:

> - *bins* = *bin* + *es*
> - *wars* = *war* + *es*

Other answers that were posted so far claim that these forms were sloppy or even wrong, because an apostrophe was missing (*bin's* and *war's*). However, at least since the latest orthographic reform, it is not typical to put an apostrophe there. One could argue whether [§ 97 of the orthographic rules](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6208) applies:

> **§ 97**
>
> Man kann den Apostroph setzen, wenn Wörter gesprochener Sprache mit Auslassungen bei schriftlicher Wiedergabe undurchsichtig sind.
>
> ---
>
> You can put the apostrophe when words of spoken language with omissions are obscure when written.

However, "Ich bins!" and "Ich wars!" aren't obscure at all. DUDEN Online substantiates what § 97 means for mergers with the pronoun *es*. In [D14 (4.)](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/apostroph#K14) they write:

> **D14**
>
> In den folgenden Fällen wird üblicherweise kein Apostroph gesetzt:
>
> …
>
> **4.** bei Verbindungen der Kurzform des Pronomens *es* mit dem vorangehenden Wort – sofern das Lesen nicht erschwert wird.
>
> ZUM BEISPIEL:
>
> - Wie gehts (auch: geht’s) dir?
> - Sie machte sichs (auch: sich’s) bequem.
> - Wenns (auch: Wenn’s) weiter nichts ist ...
> - Aber eher: Sie weiß, wo’s langgeht.
>
> ---
>
> In the following cases, no apostrophe is usually placed:
>
> …
>
> **4.** in connections of the short form of the pronoun *es* with the preceding word – as long as it does not make reading more difficult.
>
> …

In summary, the examples in your dictionary conform to the current rules.

Comment: The _-s_ and similar suffixes in spoken languages can be analyzed as [clitics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clitic) (although they're rarely called as such).